# Error using Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon

Tags: c#, .net, icons, system.drawing

I'm attempting to load an icon based on a selected file:

```
Icon iconForFile = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(filename);
```

When I run this code locally through VS, everything works fine.  However, after I deploy/install the application that contains this code, I get an error message:

"[My Program] - Unable to locate Component:
This application has failed to start because libapr_tsvn.dll was not found.  Re-installing the application may fix this problem."

Strangely enough, once I click OK, my program continues to run as expected, and the `Icon` object is set/displays correctly.  Searching around shows that this may be a dll from Tortoise SVN, which I use for version control.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Also, trying to wrap this code in a try/catch block doesn't yield an exception - it seems to be system generated and thus outside of my program's domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with Tortoise SVN.  I updated to the latest version a few days ago, didn't restart, and continued working.

My application allows the user to drag-and-drop files into a listview.  It appears that a hook for SVN runs when a drap-and-drop action occurs; since Tortoise wasn't properly installed, this hook failed and gave me the error message.  Proving once again, always restart...

Answer (score 2):

I get the feeling that this has nothing at all to do with extracting icons - your project has the libapr_tsvn.dll file referenced, and this reference needs to be removed.

Comment: this answer was close.  see my description of what happened below.